# Clearing a cookie with SimpleCookie

Tags: python, cookies

I'm trying to clear a cookie

I read the correct way to do so is to set the 'expires' field to a past time

But when trying to do so using the SimpleCookie library I get the following exception:

> Attempt to set a reserved key: expires

What's the right way to handle it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import http.cookies

c = http.cookies.SimpleCookie(os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE'))
c['hello'] = 'world'
c['hello']['expires'] = 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'
print(c)
```

You have to set the `expires` field as part of a cookie. Output:

```
Set-Cookie: hello=world; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: I already know that. But when trying to set c['hello']['expires'] I'm getting the stated exception.

Comment: This doesn't run? Can you provide some context?

Comment: cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"]) ---> cookie["expires"] = 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'
---->
Gives the above exception.

Comment: Ah. If you're clearing one cookie `hello` of SimpleCookie `c`, then you do `c['hello']['expires'] = 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'`.

Comment: After hours of dealing with these things I failed to see the obvious. thanks